# visual studio 2010 debugging gives network error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, windows-7, iis-7.5, localhost

I have an ASP.Net MVC3 app developed in VS 2010 running on Windows 7 with IIS 7.5 consuming several WCF services also part of the VS solution file and all on the same localhost.  When I debug the services they start in the WCF Test utility nicely.  When I attempt to debug the ASP.Net app I get a network error and it points to an IP address I do not recognize at all.  If I start the app from IIS using Browse *:80 (http) it works perfectly.  I can enter data, do stuff and all is wonderful.  If I attempt to just go there via http://localhost/AppFilePath from IE (not via the IIS Manager) I get a message that IE cannot display the webpage.

Does anyone have any idea where I need to even begin looking to determine what the issue is?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Check the properties of the project

Under the Web tab there is a Servers section that controls where the debugger fires and starts.